# Semantic Analysis Error in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, join, hive

I am trying to make a join on two tables using Hive SQL and I am always getting semantic analysis error

```
hive> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON
(Table1.BUYER_ID = Table2.UID);
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 1:76 Invalid Table Alias 
Table1
```

Table Structure are-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1
( 
ITEM_ID BIGINT, 
CREATED_TIME STRING, 
BUYER_ID BIGINT 
) 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table2 
( 
UID BIGINT, 
PURCHASED_ITEM ARRAY<STRUCT<PRODUCT_ID: BIGINT,TIMESTAMPS:STRING>> 
)
```

Any suggestion why is it happening?

Comment: Don't you have to specify HDFS path when creating external tables? Are these tables created successfully? Do they show up when you do `show tables`?

Comment: Yes they show up successfully in `show tables`. I haven't created these tables, these tables was there previously, I have just provided the table structure.